# How to specify data attributes with a sitecore general link without any code change?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, sitecore

We had a quick requirement from the client where they wanted to add a link to open a popup on our website. We tried of reusing a component with General link on it. The technical requirement here was just to specify a data-attribute to the anchor tag. We wanted the anchor tag created from the General link to be formed as:

```
<a href="#openPopup" data-popupData = "abc">Link</a>
```

We used the insert javascript option available for the general link to insert the javascript code to open the popup but need a way through to include the data-attribute.

Please note we need it to be done from the content tree only and no code change.

Comment: Technically you could add the data attribute in the raw values. If you need a content editor friendly solution, you'd have to extend the `Insert Javascript` form by adding a field for the data attribute.

Comment: As I mentioned, I don't want to do any extension or code changes. Isn't it possible by any other means?